# What is the word for stories/movies/poems that have a moral lesson

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I am reading [this](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=WgYGAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=moral%20lessons&hl=en&sa=X&ei=w1-JVePoI5WNuASOhZvoAg&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=moral%20lessons&f=false) book - and I have been trying to remember the word but it's eluding me.

> What is the word for stories/movies/poems that provide a moral lesson.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Allegory

(noun)
1.a representation of an abstract or spiritual meaning through concrete or material forms; figurative treatment of one subject under the guise of another.([Ref](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/allegory))

Comment: +1.. Somebody said- an allegory is like a metaphor on steroids.

Comment: +1. Worth noting that an allegory doesn't have to be a story. It can be other forms of art too.

Comment: The fact is that an allegory is not specific to a *moral lesson* , but to anything you want to represent indirectly.

Answer (score 20):

A [**parable**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/parable), for a story with human characters.

> a short allegorical story designed to illustrate or teach some truth, religious principle, or moral lesson. (Dictionary.com)

If the story features talking animals (and the like), it's a [**fable**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fable)

From Wikipedia:

> Fable is a literary genre: a succinct fictional story, in prose or verse, that features animals, mythical creatures, plants, inanimate objects, or forces of nature that are anthropomorphized (given human qualities, such as verbal communication) **and that illustrates or leads to an interpretation of a moral lesson (a "moral"),** which may at the end be added explicitly as a pithy maxim.
>
> ***A fable differs from a parable*** in that the latter excludes animals, plants, inanimate objects, and forces of nature as actors that assume speech or other powers of humankind.

Answer (score 3):

A [parable](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/parable):

> - A simple story used to illustrate a moral or spiritual lesson, as told by Jesus in the Gospels. (ODO)

An [apologue](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/apologue)

> - A moral fable, especially one with animals as characters.(ODO)
> - ***An [apologue or apolog](http://%20An%20apologue%20or%20apolog%20(from%20the%20Greek%20%E1%BC%80%CF%80%CF%8C%CE%BB%CE%BF%CE%B3%CE%BF%CF%82,%20a%20%22statement%22%20or%20%22account%22)%20is%20a%20brief%20fable%20or%20allegorical%20story%20with%20pointed%20or%20exaggerated%20details,%20meant%20to%20serve%20as%20a%20pleasant%20vehicle%20for%20a%20moral%20doctrine%20or%20to%20convey%20a%20useful%20lesson%20without%20stating%20it%20explicitly.%20Unlike%20a%20fable,%20the%20moral%20is%20more%20important%20than%20the%20narrative%20details.%20As%20with%20the%20parable,%20the%20apologue%20is%20a%20tool%20of%20rhetorical%20argument%20used%20to%20convince%20or%20persuade.)*** (from the Greek ἀπόλογος, a "statement" or "account") is a brief fable or allegorical story with pointed or exaggerated details, ***meant to serve as a pleasant vehicle for a moral doctrine or to convey a useful lesson without stating it explicitly.*** Unlike a fable, the moral is more important than the narrative details. ***As with the parable, the apologue is a tool of rhetorical argument used to convince or persuade.*** (Wikipedia)

Answer (score 3):

Such a story is a **morality tale**.

From the [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/morality-tale):

> A story or narrative from which one can derive a moral about right and wrong.

Examples:

> 'his story can be seen as a modern morality tale'
>
> 'On The Waterfront is a great morality tale about corruption and redemption'

Answer (score 1):

The book referenced indeed contains fables among other things. All of the material is provided to be ***[edifying](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/edify)***.

> **Edify**: Instruct or improve (someone) morally or intellectually

(Oxford)

Answer (score 0):

One of the exact term for that is simply

> Moral

As in moral tales, moral stories, moral fable...

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moral#Morals_in_moral_tales):

> A moral (from Latin morālis) is a message conveyed or a lesson to be
>   learned from a story or event.

[Collins:](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/moral?showCookiePolicy=true)

> The lesson to be obtained from a fable or event

Comment: A story may have a moral, but would not itself be a *moral*.